# ReSharper 2017.1 Cannot find MachineSpec Tests anymore

Tags: c#, resharper, visual-studio-2017

Just updated to the Resharper 2017.1 from 2016.3 and now, none of my MachineSpec Tests are found anymore.

Also in the ReSharper Extension Manager, there is no MSpec Runner anymore.

Am i missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you have to wait for the mspec plugin to be updated for ReSharper 2017.1